# What is the Big-O of this nested loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
int z=1; 
for（int i=0;i*i<n;i++）｛
  z*=3;
  for（int j=0;j<z;j++）{
   // Some code
  }
}
```

Answer is O(3^n). 
Is it correct?  How to figure out time complexity of nested loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outer loop: i goes from 1 to sqrt(n);
inner loop: j,z goes up to 3^(sqrt(n));

"some code" will run 1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^(sqrt(n)) times

```
let sum = 1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^(sqrt(n))
sum - 3*sum = 1 - 3(sqrt(n) + 1)
sum = 1 - 3(sqrt(n) + 1) / (1-3) = 2( 3^(sqrt(n)+1) - 1 )
```

2( 3^(sqrt(n)+1) - 1 ) << O( 3^sqrt(n) )

O(3^sqrt(n)) is more accurate

Comment: `3^sqrt(n)` is the execution time of the last iteration of outer loop, not the overall execution

Comment: you are welcome to provide a more accurate answer for the summation of the series i provided. It is definitely not O(3^n) however.

Comment: no, your complexity is the correct one, the sum of geometric progression is `b1*(q^n-1)/(q-1), q=3` which is still O(3^sqrt(n)), sorry for inconvenience

Comment: i've fleshed out the workings, was lazy to type the proof

Answer (score 1):

You could approach the problem using Sigma notation this way:

[image]